# Django Crispy Forms. Почему закомментированная строка влияет на результат ? И как это исправить?

Tags: python-3.x, django

У меня есть вот такой код формы:

```
               <form method="POST">
                    <!-- {{ form|crispy }} -->
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% if field.name == 'name' %}
                        {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group mt-5 {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %}" id="group_{{ field.name }}">
                                <!-- <label for="id_{{ field.name }}" class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label> -->
                                <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-user-run"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    {{ field }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% elif field.name == 'email' %}
                        {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %}" id="group_{{ field.name }}">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-email-83"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                    {{ field }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% elif field.name == 'message' %}
                        {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group mb-4 {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %}" id="group_{{ field.name }}">
                                {{ field }}
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-round btn-block btn-lg">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Получаю вот такой результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как только я удаляю вот этот комментарий:

`<!-- {{ form|crispy }} -->`

Результат сразу меняется и "карета" превращается в "тыкву":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я новичок и совсем не понимаю почему так происходит и как это исправить?!

Comment: Для комментариев есть специальный тег: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#comment

Comment: вариант 1 - там CSS, который нужен форме. вариант 2 - там тоже есть такой комментарий (хотя маловероятно, ибо тогда мы скорее всего увидели `-->`

Answer (score 0):

`<!-- {{ form|crispy }} -->` в даном фрагменте кода все что между скобок, включая сами скобки - не являеться html кодом. Следовательно тег crispy применяеться на вашу django форму. `<!-- -->` - работает только для html кода.